# htaccess not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2&subid=$3
```

I've edited the htaccess file. It should only use this htaccess for the main domain and not for subdomains, however subdomains still use this htaccess.

Anyone with more experience than me could point me out in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Here is my current (and working) htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2&subid=$3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# first, remove redirect to www by default if no subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subsectie=$2&subid=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Working! Didn't know you had to re-define the rewrite condition everytime. I've edited my post with the htaccess I'm using right now.

Comment: You are welcome. Also redirecting domain.com to www.domain.com will remove SEO duplicates which is good!